# Cannot filter questions on iOS Firefox

Tags: bug, mobile-web, firefox, ios

[image: dropdown]

Steps:

1. Go to any SE site and select the filter dropdown menu
2. Change the view to, say Active.
3. Hit done

Expected: The view changes. Actual: The view doesn't change and also if you click anywhere on the page, the dialog comes back up rendering the page unusable.

P.S. To have the best meta experience, try this bug on `meta.stackoverflow.com`.

P.P.S. The dark theme is just Firefox's default dark mode across all sites. It's pretty nice you should give it a shot.

Comment: No repro on Firfox for Android; must be some iOS thing

Comment: Firefox for iOS runs on WebKit, so if you want to repro, you often have better luck using a Webkit browser than Firefox. No repro for me on Chrome for Android, though. Guess it's an apple-webkit/Safari is the new IE thing.